# How to send 401 request to unlink Google account from Action

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

I am trying to allow the user of my Google action to be able to unlink their account through voice (e.g. by saying "unlink"). By doing so, they will be prompted to re-link their account when they use the action again.

I've tried returning a 401 status code but I receive the error "Can't set headers after they are sent" in the logs. The function below is triggered when the user says "unlink."

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {SignIn} = require('actions-on-google');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*'; // Enable lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({request: request, response: response});

  var accessToken = request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.user.accessToken;
  oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    access_token: accessToken
  });  

  function welcome(agent) {
    const conv = agent.conv();
    conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'));
    agent.add(conv);
  }

  function signInCheck(agent) {
    const conv = agent.conv();
    const granted = conv.arguments.get('SIGN_IN').status === 'OK';

    if(granted){
      oauth2Client.setCredentials({
        access_token: accessToken
      }); 
      agent.add(`Welcome.`);
    } 
  }

  function unlinkAccount(agent) {
    agent.add(`OK. I unlinked your account.`);

    response.status(401).send("I unlinked your account.");
    return;
  }

});
```

Comment: I think we need a more complete sample of code.  See [mcve].

Comment: Ok. I added a little more. Better?

Comment: I think its better, though I do not know the answer to your question, sorry.